# Writing reusable JsonConverters for json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm querying a service which returns a list of tags in multiple formats:

```
{
  "tags": "a,b,c"
}
```

or

```
{
  "tags": "a b c"
}
```

or

```
{
  "tags": "a+b+c"
}
```

The object that I want to deserialize this to is a `List<string>`. I've written a `TagsConverter` that implements the necessary methods in `JsonConverter` like so:

```
public class TagsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader
                .Value
                .ToString()
                .Split(' ')
                .ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (List<string>)value;
        var delimitedList = string.Join(" ", list);

        writer.WriteValue(delimitedList);
    }
}
```

Then I annotate the field in the object like so:

```
public class Foo
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(TagsConverter))]
  public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And this works, but only for tags that are separated by spaces.

However the `TagsConverter` can work in all 3 scenarios if I'm able to just change the `Split` and the `Join` functions in a parameterized fashion. But since we pass only the type to the `JsonConverter` attribute, I understand that we can't pass a "delimiter" as an argument there.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an additional `JsonConverter` [constructor overload](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConverterAttribute.cs#L74) that takes both a type ***and*** a `params object[] converterParameters` that is injected into the concrete instance of your converter.  You can take advantage of this overload to maximize your reusability.

```
public class TagsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly string _delimiter;

    public TagsConverter(string delimiter)
    {
        _delimiter = delimiter; 
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader
                .Value
                .ToString()
                .Split(_delimiter.ToCharArray())
                .ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (List<string>)value;
        var delimitedList = string.Join(_delimiter, list);

        writer.WriteValue(delimitedList);
    }
}
```

Utilizing the overload is as easy as passing it as a second parameter:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TagsConverter), " ")]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but wouldn't you have two create three separate `Foo` classes, one with each delimiter?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari what makes you think that that isn't exactly what the OP intends, based on the code provided?  As far as I can tell, the OP needs a reusable converter that can be applied to multiple classes, each taking a different delimiter, which is precisely what I've provided.  That said, if you have an alternative interpretation of the ask I'd love to hear it :).

Comment: No no, I think this is exactly what OP wants. I was only thinking whether there was an alternative that could involve using generics in `Foo`..

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari generics would only give you compile-time type variance...not compile-time or runtime ***parameter*** variance which is what the OP is after here.  I doubt generics would add any value.  Keep in mind as well, attribute parameters must be compile-time constants, so any sort of variable input wouldn't compile.

Comment: The intention was to use the same converter in different classes like David assumes. Thanks for providing this solution, didn't know this even existed :)

Answer (score 2):

If only needed for the reading/deserialization of the JSON do note that `string.Split` can take a character array `char[]`

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    return reader
            .Value
            .ToString()
            .Split(new char[]{' ', ',', '+'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToList();
}
```

Which means that the converter can handle all three delimiters when reading.

Comment: This is great too. But I found the solution proposed by David (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350500/235055) to be more idiomatic of what I wanted to do. Thank you for answering :)